# Posting data to self using jquery

Tags: php

I am trying to post some form data to self with no success.My code is as follows

```
<html>
    <title>Post to self</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.x-button').live("click", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "self.php",
                    data: $(".aj").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Data Loaded:");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

               <?php
              if(isset($_POST['submit']))
              {
             echo $_POST['firstname'];
              }
              ?>
            <form name="input" action="" class="aj" method="post">
                <article>
                    <label>Firstname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Ed" class="x-input"
                    />
                </article>
                <article>
                    <label>Lastname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe" class="x-input"
                    />
                </article>
                <article>
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="London" class="x-input"
                    />
                </article>
                <input type="submit" value="Update Options" class="x-button" />
            </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

When using `<form name="test" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">` in plain php and html it works but i can't get it to work with jquery.

Comment: Are you trying to post to an AJAX script (which would need to be a different script than the one generating the page).  Or are you simply trying to post the form?

Comment: what is the file name? is it `self.php` ? and use `$(form).seralize()`

Comment: @MikeBrant He can generate the page, and get the POSTed data from same file.

Comment: I am trying to post the form using jquery i am processing the posted data in the same php file that has the jquery and the jquery.

Comment: why you use jquery ajax when posting on same page

Comment: @diEcho Wordpress options page allows it and its less hairy this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you do not want to include the whole page to the response text so you need a statement if ajax is requested

```
    <?php
/* AJAX check  */
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

  if(isset($_POST))
  {
        print_r($_POST);
  }

}else{
?>   
<html>
    <title>Post to self</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.x-button').live("click", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "self.php",
                    data: $(".aj").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Data Loaded:");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <form name="input" action="" class="aj" method="post">
                <article>
                    <label>Firstname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Ed" class="x-input"
                    />
                </article>
                <article>
                    <label>Lastname</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe" class="x-input"
                    />
                </article>
                <article>
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="London" class="x-input"
                    />
                </article>
                <input type="submit" value="Update Options" class="x-button" />
            </form>
    </body>

</html>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: I copied the answer as is but the print_r($_POST); wont display anything.Could you kindly what you have on a fiddle?.

Comment: Change  $('.x-button').live("click", function () { to
$('.x-button').click(function(){

Then change the <input type="submit" to <input type="button"

Then change  alert("Data Loaded:"); to alert(data); so you can see if the ajax is successfully reaching the php

Comment: Instead of using `if...else...` simply `die()` at the end of the `if` statement content.

Answer (score 17):

you are mixing two approch altogether.

```
<form id="myform" action="" >
  .....
</form>
```

To send ajax request to the same page you can keep url parameter empty/removed

TRY

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.x-button').live("click", function () {
           $.post({
                  data: $('form#myform').serialize(),
                  success: function (data) {
                     alert("Data Loaded:");
                  }
              });
          });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I have this as you suggested http://jsfiddle.net/qX47K/1/ but i cannot echo the posted value successfully.

Comment: are you not getting the value in `jsfiddle` OR on your page?

Answer (score 2):

add `return false;` at the end of the inline javascript function to avoid the form gets submitted the "normal" way