# link to a piece of code that is on the same page

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say I have to following code **(code A).** If I want to put the code of the ajax_image_event.php page (code B) on the same page as this code **(code A)**, how can I do this?

Is there a way to replace the url to link to the code (code B) that is on the same page of **code A**?

**Code A**

```
$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:"ajax_image_event.php?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="+
     thumb_width+"&h="+thumb_height+"&x1="+x_axis+"&y1="+y_axis,
         cache:false,
         success:function(rsponse)
             {
     $("#cropimage").hide();
     $("#thumbs").html("");
     $("#thumbs").html("<img src='images/"+rsponse+"' />");
     }
 });
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656831/posting-data-to-self-using-jquery

Comment: Please clarify the question - this makes no sense at the moment. "pu tthe code of ... on the smae page as this code"? "replace the url to link to the code"?

Comment: I want to put the code A (the one in my question) and B (the one that's on the ajax_image_event.php page) on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['t']) && $_GET['t']==='ajax' ) {
   // Ajax will execute this code
   exit;
}
// Main page
?>
```

And in your AJAX code use

```
url: "?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="+
     thumb_width+"&h="+thumb_height+"&x1="+x_axis+"&y1="+y_axis
```

Then, your page will look like this:

=== mypage.php (start) ===

```
<?php

if( isset($_GET['t']) && $_GET['t']==='ajax' ) {

   // Ajax will execute this code

   /*
      ajax_image_event.php code goes here
   */

   exit;
}

// Here starts code executed when mypage.php is not called using ajax

/*
   Some php
*/

?>

<!-- Some HTML -->

<script type="text/javascript">

/*
   Some JS
*/

$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:"?t=ajax&img="+$("#image_name").val()+"&w="+
     thumb_width+"&h="+thumb_height+"&x1="+x_axis+"&y1="+y_axis,
         cache:false,
         success:function(rsponse)
             {
     $("#cropimage").hide();
     $("#thumbs").html("");
     $("#thumbs").html("<img src='images/"+rsponse+"' />");
     }
 });

/*
   Some JS
*/

</script>

<!-- Some HTML -->
```

=== mypage.php (end) ===

Comment: And do I have to put the url of the page I'm on?

Comment: @freddy You don't have to