# Pass data with ajax to same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i been using ajax a lot lately and been going great until now!

I am trying to post data to the same page using ajax by passing in information needed to complete my request.

Thing is, it clearly is not going into my POST because i am not getting my output and in fact.. I am getting my entire html document back as the output from the request so i know its not going into my IF.

P.s, the following ajax code works perfectly if i request to a `commands.php` page that strictly has php only in it and of course, its not the same page!

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/url/',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {testpost: "hello"}
}).done(function(data)
{
    console.log(data); //I dont receive "yayyy" but the html source
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['testpost'])) //Should return "hello" if i echo $_POST['testpost']
{
    exit("yayyy");
}
```

And yes, the PHP is at the very top of the page. Nothing above the code.

Comment: I already tried that, i only go with exit as i thought thats why i receive the html document cause the code was running right through.

Comment: Is your if statement at the top of your file?

Comment: `And yes, the PHP is at the very top of the page. Nothing above the code.`...?

Comment: The "html source" your receive, is it a 404 page?

Comment: No its my html document including my html elements etc. No output i want though!

Comment: Change `type: 'POST',data: {testpost: "hello"}` to `type: 'post',data: {"testpost": "hello"}`

Comment: Why is your ajax callback returning page html? Surely your ajax callbacks should be data returners only? Loading more than you need on an ajax request seems unecessary.

Comment: I never experienced this before, a real strange one! I dont have a header tpl or nothing. Exactly how it should. Being honest, thought this should work. May just go with external page like usual.

Comment: @JParkinson1991 he said it's not suppose to return html. That IS the problem.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Or auto router? That will load a page template regardless of url given? For example, top and tailing a site but showing a 404 page?

Comment: No none of that, i created the site myself from scratch. No engines etc so should be working. <-- Cant say that as its not! Perhaps it is a cache issue outside of my reach seeing as i cleared cache etc and flushed. Works instantly when its a sole php file.

Comment: Its strange how linking directly to a PHP file works, but not using a url. The html must be getting added in somewhere during your clean url process. .htaccess passing all requests to index.php first maybe?

Comment: Ive noticed our trying to POST data to the same page? (No wonder the HTML is being returned). Why are you doing this? Whats the aim?

Comment: Another recommendation, whilst not how you want to implement, would be to seperate your display and your PHP as much as possible. You should move the ajax callback out of your display.

Comment: Yeah i know that, i have many dedicated sections for ajax only (Sole PHP) but in this case the file im accessing is very secure as im dealing with personal information. No worries though as im already currently working on a new implement using sole PHP. At least i now know it IS possible direct ajax but some reason not working for me. Anyway! Thanks for the help guys, il leave this open to see if someone has a solution for future purposes! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post you can check to see if it is an AJAX request or not: [Posting data to self using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656831/posting-data-to-self-using-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top)

> ```
> <?php
> /* AJAX check  */
> if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
>
>   if(isset($_POST))
>   {
>         print_r($_POST);
>   }
>
> } else {
> ?>   
> <html>
> ...
> ```