# jquery ajax post to self not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am taking a value from the dropdown using jquery on change , i am using ajax to post to self, but i am not able to echo the posted variable.

```
    <form>
                <label>Select Doctor:</label>
                <select class="docdrop">
                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <option value = "123">doca</option>
                <option value = "456" >docb</option>
                </select>
              </form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.docdrop").change(function(){
        var d_Id = $(this).val();
        if(d_Id!="")
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>",
                data: {d_id1 : d_Id}, //using 'd_id1' did not make a change
                 success: function(){
                     alert(d_Id]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>


//php code in same page

        <?php
              if(isset($_POST['d_id1']))
                 $d_Id = $_POST['d_id1'];
             ?>
    <p><?php  echo $d_Id; ?></p>
```

i get the alert on success but , i am unable to echo the posted variable. i dont want to use serialize() or post the entire form. just d_Id whic i obtain in jquery

Comment: Have a look with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656831/posting-data-to-self-using-jquery

Comment: Your `success` function needs a parameter, otherwise you cannot access the server's response. I'm wondering though, the code you posted should give the result you expect, namely alert `d_Id`; how did you figure out it's not the value from the server?

Comment: @ChrisG , in fact I don't need success , i just used it to alert the jquery variable d_Id. but  i am unable to echo the $_POST['d_id'] which i am trying to send via ajax .

Comment: @Praveen What do you mean, you're  "unable to echo the $_POST['d_id']"...? Where do you expect it to appear?

Comment: @ChrisG , as you can see , i am doing a self post . i just want to echo the posted variable . I am unable to figure out why $_POST['d_id1'] isn't being set

Comment: @Praveen But you *are* echoing the variable, but only on the server. The result of that echo, a document containing something like `<p>123</p>`, is then sent back to your browser, in the background. Because that's the whole point of AJAX. You can now access this document by using the first parameter of your `success` function. However you aren't doing anything with it. - If you want the dropdown to disappear and instead see `123`, then AJAX is the wrong solution.

Comment: @ChrisG , all i want to do is get the selected value of the dropdown , into a php variable so that i can use it to query in my database and display the results in the same page. Any alternative approach?

Comment: @Praveen It seems to me the issue here is you don't fully understand how AJAX works. You want to display the results "on the same page", but do you mean by inserting them dynamically into an existing `<div>`? That's what AJAX is for. Or do you just want to navigate to a new page with results, like clicking a link? In that case you don't use AJAX.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of both methods: https://pastebin.com/QVCgPD3y Selecting a dropdown option fires a POST request in the background. Clicking the button simply submits the form.

Comment: thanks for that , but i dont want to use a submit button and can i just reload a div containing the  echo $_POST['d_id'] ? i tried jquery load , i dont understand why its not working the way i want.
i want to display the value of the selected dropdown below the dropdown , dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can do this without using  jQuery in this way :

```
<?php 
  $d_id1 ="";      
  if(isset($_POST['d_id1'])){
     $d_Id = $_POST['d_id1'];
     echo $d_Id;
     exit;
    }
 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        
   </head>
     <body>
        <form>
            <label>Select Doctor:</label>
            <select class="docdrop" >
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option value = "123">doca</option>
            <option value = "456" >docb</option>
            </select>
         </form>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("select.docdrop").change(function(){
           var d_Id = $(this).val();
             if(d_Id!="")
                {
                  $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>",
                  data: {d_id1 : d_Id}, 
                  success: function(data){
                  d_id1 = data;
                  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = d_id1;
                  console.log(data);

               }
            });
          }
       });
    });
    </script>
   <p id ="name"><?php echo $d_id1;?></p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: If they are already using the much simpler, cross-browser jQuery way, why recommend `XMLHttpRequest` instead?

Comment: @amit a jquery solution would be helpful

Comment: @Praveen you can implement in this way using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

php code execute one time on page load, so that time your variables $d_Id and $d_Id1 are not created, so it is not display any value.
also ajax execute without page refresh and all code in side success executed without any error.

Comment: but since i am posting it to same page, php code should execute again right?

Comment: if page refresh/reload again that time php execute, your code not execute onchange select box.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){
   alert(data);
}
```

You will alert the data send from backend i.e. echoed by your php part, which in your case will be the result of `<p><?php  echo $d_Id; ?></p>`, if you just need your $d_id selected without the paragraph tags change your code to `<?php  echo $d_Id; ?>`. Of course you may prefer to use JSON as output of your backend and then parse it in the `success` callback with `$.parseJSON(data)` per instance or use data type 'json' in your AJAX reques.